# Insert a blank row writing a file from a list using cat

Tags: r, for-loop, cat

using R, I have to write an output file from a list. So I think to use a 'for' loop to unlist and and write out.

```
l.spec <- list(a=c(rep("A",10)), b=c(rep("B",4)), c=c(rep("C",6)))
f <- matrix()
for(i in seq_along(l.spec)){
    f <- matrix(unlist(l.spec[i]), byrow=TRUE)
    cat(f, file="output.txt", sep="\n", append=TRUE)
}
```

Furthermor I need to insert a blank line between each level of the list to obtain an output such as:

```
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A

B
B
B
B

C
C
C
C
C
C
```

Do you have any suggestion??

Regards

Riccardo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to do what you want

`lapply(l.spec, function(x) cat(c(x, " "), file = "output.txt", sep = "\n", append = TRUE))`

Comment: @Riccardo - I'm 99.99% sure you could have modified your `for` loop to combine your data and a blank as I did, but `lapply` and friends have a certain elegance to them once you wrap your head around them :). In particular, you don't have to deal with any side effects from the iterators cluttering your workspace.